# Wordpress, html form only running php if missing fields and giving a 404 if all fields are filled?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am currently creating a form on one of my templates in Wordpress but every time I submit the form with all fields filled in I get a 404 error:

[image]

It posts correctly if some or all of the fields have been missed though.

HTML Form:

```
    <form method="POST" id="ageGatewayForm" action="">
        Day: <input type="text" name="day">
        Month: <input type="text" name="month">
        Year: <input type="text" name="year">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

PHP code on same page:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    if(!empty($_POST["day"]) && !empty($_POST["month"]) && !empty($_POST["year"])){
        //do something
    } else {
       //do something
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(isset($_POST['day']))

or

if($_POST('day')=="")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for the code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its [long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by describing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.